# Nested UnitOfWork is not working in Asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-of-work

I have a scenario where I have to use UnitOfWork for one table inside UnitOfWork for another table. It is somehow not working.

`CurrentUnitOfWork.Save()` is working as expected but the code where I am updating flag value in tbl_data table is actually not updating the flag.

Below is the code structure I have used so far:

```
using (UnitOfWork CurrentUnitofWork = new UnitOfWork())    
 {
  int empID=2134;
  //Calculation for having a value of data field     
....   
....    
...
CurrentUnitofWork.Save();

if(data==1)  
   UpdateFlag(1, empID); 
else
  UpdateFlag(0, empID);  
 }
```

Here is there Code for UpdateFlag method:

```
   public UpdateFlag(int flagValue, int empID)    
   {    
     using (UnitOfWork unitOfWork= new UnitOfWork())
       {
         tbl_data empDetails = unitOfWork.tbl_data.get(x=>x.EmpID==empID).ToList().Single();
         if (empDetails != null)
         {
           empDetails.ActiveFlag= flagValue;
           unitOfWork.tbl_data.Update(empDetails);
           unitOfWork.Save();
         }
       }
   }
```

Comment: This lacks too many details to be answerable. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Keren Caelen : one of the points that you are abusing the idea of UnityOfWork, if both have the same transaction the unity object must be chared between them and called only once

Comment: I agree @HanyHabib. But we have different tables to update. so we have these methods in out project

Comment: are you sure also that empDetails is not null?

Comment: Yes. It is not null. I can see the updated value in empDetails object. but actually it is not getting updated in table

Comment: Please help me with this... really need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue my self.

```
using (UnitOfWork CurrentUnitofWork = new UnitOfWork())    
 {
  int empID=2134;
  //Calculation for having a value of data field     
....   
....    
...
CurrentUnitofWork.Save();

if(data==1)  
   UpdateFlag(1, empID); 
else
  UpdateFlag(0, empID); 

CurrentUnitofWork.Save(); 
 }
```

Just adding a `CurrentUnitofWork.Save();`after updating inner unit of work method, solved my issue. I am not sure what is the logic behind it but it worked for me.